# How i should put some line of text in my acivity? Android

Tags: java, android

I want to write some line of text in my activity, but i can't write all in a text view, right?
What should i use and how?
I mean like this 
http://www.androidfreeware.net/img2/healthy_spark_recipes_android_3.png

Comment: You could write multiple lines in a TextView if desired yes.  Your link shows tabs being used with Fragments between them.  You'll have to do some homework to figure out what you want.

Comment: Oh, my answer wasn't what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create a String in the string folder with html code of whatever you want;

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.yourHtmlText)));
```

This will give you the opportunity to include styles and many other html stuff in your textview like h1,h2, etc

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple TextView and set custom size, font color an other options for ecah widget

Answer (score 1):

you can use multiple TextView but  you can also set a string in a textView like this:

```
textview.setText("Ingredients: \n 1) eggs \n 2) bla bla etc.. \n");
```

Comment: I agree with you but in the screenshot there are different font size and color. This is the reason why I propose to use multiple TextView

Comment: yes I agree with you ;) we can do whatever we want with TextView (or multiple)

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple text view and how to set text to **TextView**:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    // TextView example      
    TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    text.setText("Hello World! This is text");
```

### XML layout

```
    ....

    <TextView android:text="TextView"
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Put Your some lines of text, in your strings.xml file

eg.

`<string name="longtext">
   <![CDATA[
    <html><body><p style="text-align:justify">
    your paragraph text
   </p></body></html>]]>
   </string>`

and set this text in your textview by using ,

`tvTemp.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.longtext)));`